# jQuery DataTables - Inside an Bootstrap 3 Panel will cause the Search Box and Page Numbers in the Wrong Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue where I'm putting jQuery DataTable in an bootstrap 3 panel will cause the search box and page numbers to go off.

Here is the design:

[image]

I have a webpage, and will have multiple jQuery DataTable, however, with a large number of columns, it will make the webpage scrollable horizontally.

Hence my idea is to use the bootstrap 3 panel feature, and put the datatable inside, hence it will now only scroll the panel, but not the whole webpage.

[image]

Hence, the final result is a nice looking table inside the panel.

[image]

However, when the panel starts to scroll horizontally, the search and page tabs are not placed to the far right side, but in the middle, which it will look like this after it scrolls.

[image]

Can anyone point me to the right direction on how I could put the search and page tabs to the far right?

Comment: If I remember correctly the Search and Page numbers are absolutely positioned based on the parent it is rendered in.

Comment: You mean the parent as in the whole "webpage"? Is there a way to change it?

Comment: I lied in my comment. They are floated to the right. The parent would be the panel.

Comment: :))))
That's odd, why would they be in the middle.

Comment: The floats are calculated based on the parent. If a child causes the parent to expand the floats remain in their default position. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fzag33ay/1/)

Comment: Ahh, I get it. So it seems like there's no way to fix this?

Comment: You COULD use some simple jQuery to calculate the width of your search area and the width of your table and then place the search area like so..[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzag33ay/2/)

Comment: I'll try that, but I'll need the ID of the search box right?

Comment: You'll need to use the selector of the parent that contains the search. DataTables generates a div with the class `dataTables_filter` I think. You can use that as your selector.

Comment: Or you could just apply `overflow` to the table itself and save yourself some work: [Overflow](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html)

Comment: overflow, scrollx works nice. Thanks a lot! May you write up an answer and I can give a checkmark? So that people who also encounter my issue can look at the post too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to keep your search bar at the end of your table AND keep a scrollable table is to use `scrollX` in the DataTable attributes. **[ScrollX](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Simple workaround - disable default search field, make a custom input field for datatables search and place it in bootstrap panel.

```
var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable({
    // ... options ...    
});

$('.custom-input-field').keyup(function(e){
   oTable.search($(this).val());
   oTable.draw();
});
```

`setTimeout` would be a good idea in this case:

```
var searchTimer;

$('.custom-input-field').keyup(function(e){
   clearTimeout(searchTimer);
   var keyword = $(this).val();
   searchTimer = setTimeout(searchTable, 1000, keyword);
});

function searchTable(keyword){
   oTable.search(keyword);
   oTable.draw();
}
```